# Jquery: Make entire block clickable, while preserving the ability to open in a new tab/window

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, window, href, location-href

I don't want to use css to expand the link width/height etc.

With my code, the entire LI is clickable, it opens the a link found within it. I've preserved the middle mouse click to open the link in a new window.

1. I'm wondering if someone who really
   actually knows what they're doing
   can guide me in this and let me know
   if this is the best way to write
   this, or are there alterations that
   could be made to my code?
2. also: can someone help me add a
   "ctrl+left-click" to open the link
   in a new window, which is the same
   thing a middle-mouse-button click
   does, i'm just not sure how to test
   for ctrl? I thought changing the
   `else if ((e.which == 2)) {` part to `else if ((e.which
   == 2) && (e.which == 16)) {` would work, but it doesn't.

code:

```
$('li a').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().bind('click', function(e) {
                if((e.which == 1)) {
                    alert('left mouse button clicked')
                    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
                }
                else if ((e.which == 2)) {
                    alert('middle mouse button clicked')              

                        window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
                        return false;  
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: the problem with checking shift is that I'm on OSX and the shortcut is +click  (cmd+click if that didn't come through on windows), and who-knows-what-combo people have set may work as well.

Comment: oops, i said shift, but meant Ctrl. I thought ctrl and command would have the same keycode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your guide for detecting which keys are pressed (it's all through the event coming in): http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Note that on OSX it's impossible in most browsers.